# What Permissions Are Needed for Selecting Data and Viewing All Schema?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm attempting to create a role in Azure SQL such that the user can perform Select operations, view all schema (but not modify schema) but not perform any writes or execute stored procs. Granting a user Select permission gets me close. However, the user cannot see any stored procs or scalar functions.

So, I want to allow the user to see all schema definitions, not modify any schema objects and perform Selects. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about AzureDB, but on local installs, granting `VIEW ANY DEFINITION` securable will allow them to view the definitions of SPs and views.

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer - This gets me close enough. If you want to create this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the `VIEW ANY DEFINITION` securable to the user.

That will allow them to see SP and view definitions but not allow them to change it.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175808(v=sql.105).aspx